# Ruby on Rails 3.2.1 doesn't show images on Heroku under Nivo slider

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nivo-slider

My Ruby on Rails 3.2.1 APP doesn't show pictures when it is uploaded on Heroku and I really don't know where is the problem. On localhost:3000 all is working prefect. I have made a test and added a picture in content, not under Nivo slider tags and all is perfect, but under Nivo my app doesn't displaying anything.

Nivo slider tags:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
    <div class="ribbon"></div>
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
        <%=image_tag "/assets/birz.JPG"%>
        <%=image_tag "100.jpg"%>
        <%=image_tag "102.jpg"%> 
        <%=image_tag "103.jpg"%> 
        <%=image_tag "104.jpg"%> 
        <%=image_tag "105.jpg"%> 
        <%=image_tag "106.jpg"%> 
        <%=image_tag "107.jpg"%> 
        <%=image_tag "108.jpg"%> 
        <%=image_tag "109.jpg"%> 
        <%=image_tag "110.jpg"%> 
        <%=image_tag "111.jpg"%> 
        <%=image_tag "112.jpg"%> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**production.rb**

```
  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true
```

**Heroku stack:**

```
  aspen-mri-1.8.6
  bamboo-mri-1.9.2
  bamboo-ree-1.8.7
* cedar (beta)
```

Comment: Well where are your files stored in your app? Are you adding them to your app, or are you uploading them to the app?

Comment: I am adding them to my app. Files are under app/assets/images folder.

Answer (score 1):

On config/environments/production.rb, check this configuration:

```
config.serve_static_assets
```

Comment: After enabling `config.server_static_assets` heroku is showing this error: `100.JPG isn't precompiled`

Comment: @RydelHouse hi, could you post the production.rb file(specifically the lines with config.assets....). What stack are you currently on, in heroku(run: "heroku stack" to find out). Have you precompiled your assets in development? I was faced with a similar problem some time back. I found some help from this <a href="http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/03/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-using.html">heroku doc</a>

Comment: I have updated my question. I don't precompile assets in development. Can you post this link one more time? Something isn't working with it.

Answer (score 1):

My production.rb looks like this(worth a try):

```
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.digest = true
```

I found this to work for me because i precompile the assets in development(i have followed the article [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar)  and i use option 1. to precompile locally in development). This is what i do

```
1. First precompile assets in development run: "bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
```

"A public/assets directory will be created. Inside this directory you’ll find a manifest.yml which includes the md5sums of the compiled assets." - source: heroku docs

```
2. Then save to git and push to heroku
```

See if you still get same error in production app(if yes, then i am not sure what to do).

In my app whenever i precompile assets locally this causes my development stylesheets and javascript to go crazy :( . To solve go open environment/development.rb and change this line:

```
config.assets.debug = true
```

to

```
config.assets.debug = false
```

Also remove the public/assets directory that assets precompile created locally. Restart server and hopefully it should work again. It seems to be a tricky thing to figure out correctly(asset pipeline), but hopefully this will help.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping, but this not resolved my problem. :(

Comment: @RydelHouse Thanks, worth a try. Asset pipeline can be tricky sometimes, just play around with it, hopefully it will work